# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "globalize":

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Hi everyone I have recently started developing with this framework, I am having difficulties in starting a project locally.
When I go to run a

> bundle install

I get this error message:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "globalize":   In Gemfile:
    globalize java

    globalize-accessors java was resolved to 0.2.1, which depends on
      globalize (>= 5.0.0, ~> 5.0)

Could not find gem 'globalize (>= 5.0.0, ~> 5.0)', which is required by gem 'globalize-accessors', in any of the relevant sources:   https://github.com/globalize/globalize.git (at master@bcfa30f)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "globalize-accessors":   In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    globalize-accessors (= 0.2.1)

  In Gemfile:
    globalize-accessors java

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

this is the part of the gemfile concerned:

```
########## Globalization
gem "route_translator", git: "https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator.git"

gem 'activemodel-serializers-xml'
gem 'globalize-accessors'
gem 'globalize', github: 'globalize/globalize'
gem 'kaminari', github: "amatsuda/kaminari", branch: '0-17-stable'
gem "kaminari-i18n"
```

i also tried to run bundle update but it didn't fix the problem

> Ruby version:2.3.3
> gem -v:2.5.2

Answer (score 2):

The version of `globalize` in your gemfile seems not to correspond to the version required for `globalize-accessors`.

Try installing globalize like so :
`gem 'globalize', "~> 5.0"`